# Subscript indices must be real positive integers or logicals in neural networks matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, integer, backpropagation

I tried to apply neural network function in GUI matlab.

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
P = load('data.mat','Z');

nR = size(P.Z,2);
min_P = min(P.Z,[],2);
max_P = max(P.Z,[],2);

minmax = [min_P, max_P];
P = ((0.8*(P.Z - repmat(min_P,1, nR))./repmat(max_P - min_P,1,nR))) + 0.1;


Px = load('minmax.txt');

net = newff(minmax(Px),[3 9 4],{'logsig','tansig','logsig'},'trainrp');

net.IW{1,1} = load('bobot1.txt');
net.b{1} = load('bias1.txt');

net.LW{2,1} = load('bobot2');
net.b{2} = load('bias2');

net.LW{3,2} = load('bobot3');
net.b{3} = load('bias3.txt');

[Y] = sim(net,P);
result = round(Y);

sum_result= sum(result);

normal = (sum(sum_result(:) == 0));
set(handles.edit1,'String',num2str(normal));
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
??? Subscript indices must either be real positive
integers or logicals.

Error in ==> test>pushbutton1_Callback at 95
net = newff(minmax(Px),[3 9
4],{'logsig','tansig','logsig'},'trainrp');

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ==> test at 42
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in ==>
@(hObject,eventdata)test('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

The command works properly in training and testing session, I don't know why it's happened in GUI. 
Also the minmax data should be consist within 0-0.9 range data because my data were in that range. Thank you in advance.

```
minmax data: 
  1.0054496e-001  1.0803815e-001
  1.0000000e-001  1.0490463e-001
  3.8269755e-001  9.0000000e-001
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of 'minmax.txt' and the result of the line `Px = load('minmax.txt');`

Comment: Plese check my update @mhopeng. I've uploaded my minmax data, but I don't really understand of your request about the result of the line Px

Comment: Put `disp(Px)` immediately after the load statement to verify that you get the matrix you expect from the text file.

Comment: FYI `newff` is obsolete as of 2010. What version of matlab do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing the array `minmax` with `Px`, that you have loaded. You will probably have to either do `Px = logical(Px)` if it is supposed to be 1's and 0's, or do `Px = int(Px)` if Px is a list of integers.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, my data is a list of integer (0,1-0,9) but I still get the same error message

Comment: What is Px supposed to be?

Comment: Px is supposed to load my minmax data, but since I convert my minmax data to integers (as your suggestion), it contains integers data. You can see my minmax data in my question above

Comment: What are you expecting minmax(Px) to do?

Comment: To find minmax data. But I've tried to change it into net=newff(Px,[3 9 ...
but I still get the same error message

Comment: If you are trying to use the minmax function, you need to rename the variable you created called minmax. The variable is overriding the function name.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a variable called "minmax" at this line:

`minmax = [min_P, max_P];`

but ["minmax"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/minmax.html) is a Matlab function that takes a array argument. This function would work fine with your input data from minmax.txt. I assume that you want to use this function at the line that causes the error, so change the name of the variable "minmax" to something else, for example:

`minmax_P = [min_P, max_P];`

However, I think there are some other issues with your code:

1) Why do you need to process the data from the file "minmax.txt"? It already looks like it is min/max data, and it does not change if you use the function `minmax()` on it. Can you use it as the function argument directly, like:

`net = newff(Px,[3 9...`

2) Are you sure that you need the line:

`minmax = [min_P, max_P];`  ? It does not seem to have any purpose (except to cause bugs :)

Comment: I tried both of your suggestion but I still get the same error message. I tried to rewrite my command even tried in new GUI, but it still didn't work.
Please help me :(

Comment: Check your syntax for `newff`. The help says: `net = newff(P,T,S,TF,BTF,BLF,PF,IPF,OPF,DDF)`. You are missing the input `S`.